# increase a ID by 1 - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Morning,
I would like to know how to increase the number by 1 in the code behind of a asp.NET c# page.

essentially i have

```
<message id>1</message id>
```

which needs to be increased for each record i have. How would i go about doing this in my code behind? so it would then look like the below...

```
<message id>1</message id> 
<message id>2</message id>
<message id>3</message id>
```

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I am building some XML which has the below in it. All i need is for the message id to be increased by 1 for each item/product.

```
 foreach (var product in products)
        {
            xml.Append(string.Format("<Message>"));
            xml.Append(string.Format("<MessageID>1</MessageID>"));
```

Comment: Is this in a databound context, like a ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a=1;
foreach (var product in products)
        {
            xml.Append(string.Format("<Message>"));
            xml.Append(string.Format("<MessageID>"+a+"</MessageID>"));
            a++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
        {
            xml.Append(string.Format("<Message>"));
            xml.Append(string.Format("<MessageID>" + i+1 + "</MessageID>"));
}
```

When you want a product you would index in using:

`products[i]`

edit: the array starts with 0, so u should declare the i variable with 0